# Filling a form with C#

Tags: c#, forms, pdf, ms-word

I am researching filling out a form programatically. I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557480/populate-a-form-and-print-out-document) which is pretty similar to what we want to do. But I have a few other questions.

1. Is there any examples of this online to get me started?
2. We have some areas where we have circle this option or X that option. How would that be handled?

The form itself is in PDF and Word formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used ABC PDF with some success : http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm

Comment: Lol, +1 for beating me to the punch :)

Comment: They also win the award for best company name - webSupergoo - fantastic!

Comment: Sounds like ABCpdf might be the one to look at. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We do programatic form filling of PDF's at my place of business A LOT! Honestly, I have looked into rolling a custom solution in the past, but we use a third party library called [ABCPDF](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I've used the SDK from Mi-Co :

http://mi-corporation.com/page.php?pageid=13

It's awesome software that lets you build form software with .Net and is ink enabled for the tablet pc.  I would look into buying something like this if you need a full featured form package as it would cost more to develop from scratch.  It allows you to save the forms on a server and extract the data from the form into a database in addition to rendering it to tif or pdf.  The SDK has hooks everywhere for customization.

If you just need a simple form than it may be too much.